# PHPUnit - Remote Code Coverage

Tags: curl, selenium, phpunit, code-coverage

I have a full REST project. Test cases call the REST APIc through cURL. How can I add this request to code coverage report? I know that PHPUnit-Selenium can collect code coverage report through prepend/append PHP files, maybe somebody can show me an example of how this works?

Comment: good question. I am also looking for the same answer

Comment: Got the same question. Easy to do in node.js, seems to be a bit more of a challenge in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit dated but just in case it could be useful for anybody else

The way I did it, first of my test case class extends the Selenium Test Case class

It is easier that way so that the test Id is generated and selenium calls the phpunit_coverage.php script automatically at the end of the test

All I needed to do is to grab this id ($this->testId) and send as a cookie in the curl request:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPUNIT_SELENIUM_TEST_ID=' . $this->testId);

That way the append/prepend scripts can collect the code coverage stats

if your test case doesn't extends the selenium test case class, you can still generate a unique Id yourself, and then make another curl request to run the phpunit_coverage.php

Hope it helps